# Admin user get message higher level of permission to edit taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

i can't edit taxonomy even i created  wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=portfolio-filter&post_type=portfolio
message show
[image]